# how to translate a SAS mixed model code into R?

Tags: r, model, mixed

I tried to apply a similar mixed model that I used in SAS for other analysis in R. I need to understand how would the initial code be written in R.
It would be a mixed model with repeated measure and random factor.

This is what I used in SAS:

```
proc sort data=comp1; by age order subj light clock;
  PROC MIXED DATA = comp1;by age;
  CLASS  subj order light clock;

  MODEL mel = light clock light*clock/DDFM = KR;
  RANDOM subj order/ subject=subj ;
  Repeated clock /TYPE = ar(1)  ;


  LSMEANS light * clock/PDIFF CL;
ods output  diffs=diffcm1 ;
run;
```

Do you know how to write this in R?
Thanks

Comment: This might help: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/corr_braindump.html

Comment: This page shows *many* R and SAS codes (side by side) that do the same analysis; I find it very useful: http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/p/statistics-examples.html.